# Modified kmeans algorithm returns the wrong answer

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I am trying to create a kmeans algorithm that is based on the Earth Movers Distance instead of the Euclidean distance. However, when I run it, it just returns the same value for all data points.

The input is an dxn matrix containing all of my n probability distributions.

Here is an example of running the algorithm. The clusters for my data of length 169 should be much more distributed. I've also tried running it for more iterations to no avail.

```
distribution = {}
num_bins = 10
for i in data:
    distribution[i] = np.histogram(data[i], bins = num_bins)[0] / len(data[i])

Z = np.zeros((len(data), num_bins))
for i in range(len(Z)):
    Z[i] = distribution[list(distribution)[i]]
Z = Z.T
ans = k_means_algorithm(Z, 8, proportionally_random_k)

res = points_to_clusters(Z, ans)
print(res)

[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 3. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 4. 1. 0. 4. 1. 1. 1. 4. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 4. 2. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 3. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.
  1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.
  1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  1.]]
```

Here is my code:

```
def k_random(X, k):
   random_idx = np.random.permutation(X.shape[1])
   centroids = X[:, random_idx[:k]]
   return centroids

def points_to_clusters(X, centroids):
    assignment = np.zeros(len(X[0]))
    for i in range(len(X[0])):
        min_dist = 100000000
        for j in range(len(centroids[0])):
            cur_dist = scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance(X[:, i], centroids[:, j])
            #cur_dist = np.linalg.norm(X[:, I] - centroids[:, j])
            #EMD vs Norm
            if cur_dist < min_dist:
                assignment[i] = j
                min_dist = cur_dist
    assignment = np.array([assignment])
    return assignment

def compute_centroids(X, k, cluster_assignments, old_centroids):
    dimensions = X.shape[0]
    centroids = np.zeros((dimensions, k))
    for j in range(k):
        new_centroid = np.mean(X[:, cluster_assignments.squeeze()==j], axis=1)
        if np.isnan(new_centroid).any():
            centroids[:,j] = old_centroids[:,j]
        else:
            centroids[:,j] = np.mean(X[:, cluster_assignments.squeeze()==j], axis=1)
    return centroids


def k_means_algorithm(X, k, random_init, max_iters = 1000, return_obj=False):
    centroids = random_init(X,k)
    cluster_assignments = points_to_clusters(X, centroids)
    new_centroids = compute_centroids(X, k, cluster_assignments, centroids)
    counter = 0
    while not np.array_equal(centroids,new_centroids) and counter < max_iters:
        centroids = new_centroids
        cluster_assignments = points_to_clusters(X, centroids)
        new_centroids = compute_centroids(X, k, cluster_assignments, centroids)
        counter += 1
    return centroids

def proportionally_random_k(X, k):
    centroids = [X[:, np.random.randint(X.shape[1])]]
    for other_centroids in range(k - 1):
        distances = []
        for i in range(X.shape[1]):
            point = X[:, i]
            d = float("inf")
            for j in range(len(centroids)):
                temp_dist = np.linalg.norm(point - centroids[j])
                d = min(d, temp_dist)
            distances.append(d)
        distances = np.array(distances)
        next_centroid = X[:, np.argmax(distances)]
        centroids.append(next_centroid)
        distances = []
    return np.asarray(centroids).T
```

Here is my answer when running the Norm vs EMD.

```
k_means_algorithm(Z, 8, k_random, max_iters=1000)
```

Note that the only thing that changes between the two codes is the line that is highlighted in the function points_to_clusters, which specifies which points get mapped to what clusters.

Norm: About what I expected, well distributed clusters.

```
[[6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 7. 7.
  6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 7. 7. 6. 6.
  6. 6. 0. 6. 0. 0. 0. 4. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 7. 2. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  4. 4. 2. 2. 5. 4. 2. 2. 2. 2. 7. 7. 0. 0. 0. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 2. 4. 2. 2.
  5. 5. 7. 7. 4. 4. 4. 4. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 7. 7. 4. 4. 5. 4. 5. 5.
  5. 5. 5. 5. 7. 3. 5. 5. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5. 3. 3. 3. 5. 3. 3.
  3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 7. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
  3.]]
```

EMD: Gave the same cluster to all distributions. Clearly not right. It should be much more distributed.

```
[[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
  2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
  2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
  2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
  2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
  2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
  2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
  2.]]
```

Here is a sample of the data that I used when running the above cluster function.

```
[[0.41 0.46 0.35 0.45 0.39 0.42 0.38 0.38 0.27 0.29 0.24 0.3  0.18 0.19
 0.07 0.12 0.1  0.09 0.06 0.09 0.07 0.05 0.03 0.05 0.35 0.4  0.36 0.42
 0.36 0.43 0.31 0.31 0.22 0.29 0.16 0.18 0.06 0.11 0.06 0.05 0.1  0.06
 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.02 0.39 0.35 0.34 0.38 0.31 0.36 0.23 0.23 0.24 0.2
 0.12 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.05 0.03 0.03 0.05 0.03 0.38 0.39 0.29 0.32
 0.26 0.24 0.17 0.17 0.07 0.1  0.03 0.1  0.05 0.06 0.05 0.03 0.02 0.03
 0.29 0.37 0.24 0.21 0.16 0.15 0.11 0.1  0.13 0.14 0.03 0.06 0.03 0.13
 0.03 0.03 0.14 0.18 0.17 0.11 0.08 0.09 0.07 0.04 0.05 0.03 0.04 0.02
 0.03 0.04 0.16 0.15 0.1  0.09 0.03 0.1  0.03 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.03 0.01
 0.09 0.07 0.06 0.08 0.03 0.04 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06 0.04 0.04 0.04
 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.03 0.04 0.03 0.03 0.04 0.04 0.01 0.01 0.05
 0.02 0.01 0.03 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.01 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.   0.02
 0.01]
[0.04 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.05 0.05 0.04 0.15 0.16 0.18 0.2  0.22 0.22
 0.21 0.22 0.14 0.16 0.19 0.17 0.1  0.09 0.12 0.14 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.04
 0.04 0.06 0.13 0.14 0.2  0.23 0.24 0.23 0.18 0.19 0.13 0.18 0.14 0.17
 0.1  0.1  0.13 0.13 0.02 0.05 0.04 0.05 0.12 0.11 0.14 0.21 0.19 0.25
 0.18 0.19 0.1  0.21 0.19 0.19 0.1  0.12 0.13 0.18 0.03 0.07 0.13 0.11
 0.12 0.2  0.25 0.23 0.21 0.23 0.13 0.21 0.18 0.19 0.1  0.09 0.15 0.12
 0.11 0.11 0.21 0.19 0.13 0.28 0.21 0.19 0.15 0.24 0.23 0.17 0.1  0.14
 0.1  0.14 0.24 0.26 0.22 0.23 0.18 0.2  0.12 0.19 0.12 0.14 0.11 0.08
 0.11 0.14 0.18 0.22 0.2  0.24 0.13 0.14 0.11 0.14 0.11 0.1  0.16 0.04
 0.21 0.21 0.07 0.09 0.06 0.08 0.04 0.09 0.06 0.03 0.1  0.11 0.08 0.07
 0.08 0.1  0.06 0.04 0.07 0.11 0.05 0.07 0.08 0.06 0.11 0.04 0.07 0.08
 0.04 0.05 0.03 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.02
 0.  ]
[0.03 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.03 0.03 0.01 0.01 0.07 0.09
 0.12 0.15 0.14 0.15 0.09 0.17 0.21 0.2  0.09 0.09 0.03 0.01 0.01 0.02
 0.02 0.04 0.03 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06 0.06 0.18 0.15 0.13 0.15 0.13 0.17
 0.18 0.23 0.07 0.09 0.01 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.02 0.01 0.03 0.03 0.05 0.04
 0.14 0.15 0.15 0.13 0.18 0.18 0.21 0.18 0.1  0.1  0.01 0.02 0.01 0.01
 0.02 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.12 0.15 0.18 0.08 0.16 0.14 0.22 0.23 0.1  0.08
 0.   0.01 0.01 0.02 0.06 0.06 0.1  0.13 0.11 0.08 0.16 0.15 0.19 0.08
 0.11 0.1  0.02 0.02 0.05 0.07 0.13 0.17 0.12 0.19 0.16 0.17 0.22 0.22
 0.13 0.09 0.05 0.06 0.15 0.13 0.15 0.16 0.17 0.13 0.17 0.25 0.08 0.2
 0.12 0.12 0.18 0.16 0.14 0.14 0.11 0.14 0.12 0.16 0.18 0.19 0.14 0.12
 0.12 0.14 0.09 0.13 0.14 0.14 0.14 0.13 0.13 0.1  0.16 0.1  0.1  0.11
 0.13 0.18 0.1  0.08 0.05 0.07 0.03 0.06 0.06 0.02 0.01 0.03 0.01 0.02
 0.02]
[0.07 0.11 0.08 0.07 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.1  0.06 0.05 0.07 0.05 0.06 0.05
 0.05 0.05 0.11 0.11 0.09 0.1  0.12 0.14 0.3  0.26 0.05 0.06 0.05 0.05
 0.05 0.04 0.03 0.05 0.03 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.04 0.12 0.11 0.1  0.1
 0.14 0.12 0.21 0.25 0.04 0.05 0.07 0.04 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.05 0.06 0.05
 0.08 0.07 0.1  0.1  0.06 0.06 0.08 0.09 0.19 0.13 0.03 0.04 0.03 0.02
 0.04 0.03 0.05 0.04 0.05 0.05 0.1  0.08 0.05 0.07 0.06 0.11 0.23 0.23
 0.04 0.03 0.02 0.02 0.03 0.01 0.03 0.05 0.09 0.04 0.1  0.07 0.11 0.11
 0.21 0.21 0.03 0.02 0.03 0.02 0.05 0.04 0.09 0.1  0.06 0.1  0.07 0.16
 0.17 0.16 0.03 0.02 0.03 0.03 0.1  0.08 0.14 0.1  0.12 0.08 0.17 0.13
 0.02 0.04 0.07 0.08 0.15 0.16 0.16 0.12 0.2  0.17 0.06 0.07 0.13 0.13
 0.12 0.1  0.17 0.16 0.15 0.16 0.07 0.15 0.19 0.17 0.08 0.16 0.15 0.18
 0.09 0.15 0.27 0.17 0.1  0.09 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.11 0.12 0.08 0.02 0.03
 0.02]
[0.13 0.12 0.13 0.11 0.14 0.1  0.09 0.13 0.08 0.13 0.12 0.09 0.13 0.08
 0.1  0.09 0.09 0.12 0.13 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.01 0.04 0.11 0.14 0.11 0.14
 0.09 0.11 0.11 0.12 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.09 0.13 0.08 0.1  0.1  0.09 0.09
 0.09 0.11 0.05 0.08 0.1  0.1  0.11 0.08 0.06 0.11 0.09 0.06 0.08 0.06
 0.1  0.06 0.1  0.07 0.08 0.05 0.12 0.11 0.07 0.1  0.08 0.04 0.06 0.07
 0.08 0.06 0.05 0.09 0.07 0.07 0.05 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.12 0.13 0.06 0.07
 0.03 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.07 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.05 0.05
 0.06 0.07 0.   0.02 0.05 0.03 0.06 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.05 0.05 0.06 0.04
 0.07 0.06 0.04 0.03 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.06 0.08 0.05 0.05 0.03 0.09
 0.02 0.02 0.06 0.01 0.04 0.07 0.06 0.1  0.06 0.08 0.03 0.01 0.04 0.06
 0.1  0.11 0.06 0.07 0.03 0.03 0.11 0.14 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.13 0.08 0.06
 0.09 0.1  0.21 0.24 0.31 0.25 0.18 0.18 0.22 0.22 0.15 0.13 0.07 0.08
 0.01]
[0.13 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.11 0.14 0.14 0.11 0.15 0.12 0.09 0.12 0.09 0.11
 0.07 0.07 0.11 0.09 0.09 0.08 0.09 0.1  0.09 0.08 0.15 0.11 0.15 0.13
 0.15 0.13 0.11 0.13 0.15 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.11 0.08 0.08 0.06 0.08
 0.1  0.06 0.09 0.07 0.13 0.17 0.13 0.17 0.16 0.14 0.13 0.13 0.08 0.13
 0.11 0.1  0.1  0.09 0.07 0.12 0.07 0.09 0.09 0.11 0.16 0.16 0.14 0.15
 0.11 0.15 0.1  0.11 0.1  0.11 0.09 0.11 0.07 0.09 0.09 0.09 0.05 0.09
 0.15 0.12 0.11 0.12 0.16 0.12 0.1  0.1  0.12 0.13 0.09 0.13 0.07 0.08
 0.09 0.07 0.12 0.13 0.1  0.11 0.08 0.06 0.08 0.07 0.09 0.08 0.08 0.1
 0.07 0.12 0.07 0.04 0.05 0.05 0.07 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.09 0.07 0.08 0.06
 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.02 0.05 0.03 0.05 0.07 0.05 0.07 0.03 0.02 0.02 0.02
 0.03 0.05 0.04 0.05 0.02 0.02 0.03 0.02 0.05 0.05 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.04
 0.04 0.04 0.12 0.15 0.16 0.21 0.31 0.3  0.26 0.2  0.21 0.24 0.11 0.17
 0.05]
[0.02 0.04 0.02 0.06 0.03 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.05 0.05 0.07 0.06 0.08 0.09
 0.07 0.06 0.05 0.05 0.07 0.08 0.04 0.06 0.03 0.02 0.07 0.05 0.05 0.06
 0.06 0.05 0.05 0.1  0.09 0.09 0.07 0.08 0.08 0.06 0.06 0.1  0.06 0.04
 0.02 0.05 0.02 0.04 0.05 0.09 0.08 0.06 0.07 0.1  0.11 0.11 0.08 0.09
 0.06 0.12 0.09 0.09 0.06 0.07 0.06 0.07 0.05 0.04 0.09 0.08 0.12 0.11
 0.13 0.12 0.09 0.1  0.12 0.09 0.11 0.1  0.1  0.09 0.05 0.04 0.06 0.05
 0.14 0.13 0.13 0.13 0.12 0.13 0.13 0.14 0.09 0.11 0.09 0.09 0.07 0.1
 0.04 0.07 0.16 0.14 0.17 0.15 0.09 0.15 0.14 0.12 0.13 0.1  0.1  0.09
 0.09 0.05 0.17 0.16 0.12 0.13 0.12 0.13 0.09 0.11 0.07 0.1  0.08 0.07
 0.17 0.15 0.13 0.16 0.09 0.1  0.08 0.07 0.11 0.09 0.13 0.12 0.08 0.1
 0.07 0.1  0.05 0.08 0.06 0.08 0.07 0.02 0.04 0.07 0.04 0.02 0.04 0.06
 0.05 0.07 0.03 0.09 0.1  0.12 0.08 0.11 0.11 0.16 0.18 0.16 0.24 0.22
 0.06]
[0.01 0.02 0.03 0.02 0.05 0.06 0.03 0.05 0.03 0.03 0.05 0.07 0.04 0.05
 0.08 0.1  0.09 0.1  0.07 0.12 0.09 0.11 0.1  0.1  0.03 0.05 0.03 0.04
 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.06 0.07 0.06 0.05 0.1  0.1  0.12 0.1  0.14
 0.09 0.1  0.11 0.1  0.04 0.03 0.03 0.06 0.03 0.03 0.06 0.05 0.06 0.07
 0.04 0.08 0.11 0.1  0.1  0.11 0.11 0.12 0.11 0.15 0.03 0.09 0.06 0.07
 0.06 0.03 0.07 0.07 0.08 0.08 0.12 0.1  0.1  0.09 0.1  0.11 0.12 0.14
 0.06 0.06 0.05 0.07 0.07 0.05 0.07 0.06 0.05 0.1  0.07 0.11 0.11 0.16
 0.11 0.12 0.07 0.06 0.05 0.08 0.13 0.12 0.1  0.1  0.08 0.13 0.15 0.11
 0.09 0.13 0.1  0.14 0.08 0.11 0.11 0.11 0.1  0.11 0.11 0.13 0.12 0.12
 0.1  0.16 0.13 0.19 0.12 0.14 0.15 0.13 0.1  0.1  0.18 0.18 0.12 0.16
 0.12 0.14 0.16 0.13 0.14 0.17 0.13 0.14 0.11 0.1  0.11 0.14 0.08 0.08
 0.08 0.05 0.01 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.09 0.04 0.09 0.07 0.09 0.13 0.24 0.2
 0.34]
[0.04 0.01 0.05 0.03 0.04 0.03 0.03 0.04 0.04 0.03 0.05 0.02 0.04 0.04
 0.08 0.03 0.04 0.06 0.06 0.04 0.08 0.1  0.1  0.11 0.04 0.04 0.05 0.05
 0.02 0.04 0.04 0.02 0.06 0.06 0.06 0.05 0.04 0.06 0.06 0.05 0.07 0.08
 0.11 0.09 0.13 0.11 0.04 0.06 0.03 0.03 0.08 0.05 0.04 0.05 0.03 0.03
 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.08 0.08 0.11 0.11 0.08 0.08 0.04 0.03 0.04 0.04
 0.04 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.05 0.04 0.08 0.06 0.1  0.09 0.1  0.06 0.12 0.11
 0.05 0.03 0.05 0.08 0.06 0.07 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.08 0.1  0.08
 0.14 0.1  0.04 0.05 0.04 0.08 0.06 0.06 0.08 0.08 0.1  0.11 0.07 0.07
 0.1  0.14 0.06 0.07 0.06 0.06 0.08 0.08 0.1  0.12 0.1  0.08 0.15 0.18
 0.08 0.07 0.07 0.1  0.11 0.12 0.14 0.13 0.12 0.17 0.08 0.13 0.15 0.13
 0.15 0.12 0.16 0.2  0.18 0.11 0.17 0.18 0.15 0.21 0.23 0.25 0.26 0.23
 0.27 0.25 0.03 0.02 0.04 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.07 0.06 0.1  0.09
 0.27]
[0.12 0.1  0.18 0.1  0.1  0.06 0.14 0.08 0.13 0.11 0.11 0.08 0.1  0.07
 0.17 0.1  0.14 0.07 0.14 0.05 0.11 0.06 0.13 0.1  0.13 0.1  0.17 0.07
 0.16 0.07 0.15 0.08 0.13 0.06 0.12 0.09 0.11 0.09 0.16 0.07 0.15 0.08
 0.12 0.08 0.13 0.12 0.18 0.1  0.16 0.11 0.12 0.05 0.12 0.09 0.14 0.08
 0.12 0.09 0.12 0.07 0.12 0.08 0.12 0.09 0.12 0.09 0.14 0.08 0.12 0.11
 0.14 0.12 0.12 0.08 0.12 0.09 0.09 0.07 0.11 0.1  0.11 0.12 0.08 0.08
 0.14 0.13 0.13 0.1  0.15 0.09 0.15 0.12 0.13 0.07 0.11 0.05 0.17 0.07
 0.11 0.09 0.18 0.12 0.13 0.11 0.15 0.08 0.17 0.09 0.14 0.1  0.11 0.11
 0.14 0.08 0.15 0.11 0.15 0.11 0.17 0.12 0.15 0.1  0.12 0.09 0.1  0.09
 0.16 0.12 0.19 0.11 0.19 0.11 0.19 0.14 0.16 0.1  0.15 0.13 0.2  0.16
 0.17 0.11 0.16 0.11 0.15 0.15 0.18 0.12 0.16 0.12 0.12 0.12 0.16 0.12
 0.19 0.12 0.17 0.18 0.18 0.15 0.17 0.15 0.13 0.12 0.14 0.15 0.19 0.14
 0.22]]
```

Comment: Does your code work correctly with the Eucledian distance? What are its expected and actual outputs?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
The bounty is cool and all, but you really should do _some_ debugging to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @pts It does. While I don't have an exact matrix in mind, I do know that every cluster should be assigned a nonzero amount of times.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi If I hadn't tried to debug it I wouldn't be putting a bounty on it.

Comment: To make it easy for others to reproduce your results, please post the following files: 1. A single .py program (full source code, including imports) using the Eucledian distance and printing the output. Also make it set the random seed to a constant. 2. Actual output of #1 on your system. 3. A single .py program using the Earth Movers distance and printing the output. 4. Actual output of #3 on your system. 5. Expected output of #3. -- Make sure that the boundary is clear between these files in your question.

Comment: @pts Due to the nature of the topic, I can't share it in its entirety, but the vectors given are just normalized distributions, as shown in the top code snippet. The only thing that changes between the two versions is one line, that is noted in the points_to_clusters function.

Comment: I would expect kmeans with the EMD to behave bizarrely.  Note that EMD([0,1], [1,0]) == 0.  When we take the mean of these two points, we get [0.5, 0.5], which is further from both than they are from each other.  This destroys the intuition behind kmeans.

Comment: My point here is that your assessment that the solution you are getting is "Clearly not right" is anything but clear.  I would honestly be surprised to find that the EMD behaved similarly to the Euclidean norm w.r.t. kmeans.

Comment: There is probably a sane way to take a "mean" between the points that isn't the usual add and divide by n that has a good interpretation in terms of distributions.  For example, your 10 points are estimators of the deciles of the distribution.  Averaging the deciles of two distributions seems sane in the sense that we would get the deciles of the "average" distribution in some sense. To accomplish this, you can take the mean as usual, but you first want to `sort` all of your data points.

Comment: [`ndarray.sort` accepts an axis as an argument](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html), so you can probably do this to `Z` right up top.

Comment: You need to provide a sample input for the `data` variable.  I've tried 2d and 1d arrays for `data` and I get errors - i.e. It's not clear what you are feeding in, and if we don't know what the input is, we can't possibly help with the output.

Comment: @Him I added a small sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code. But: The standard/best known [k-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is Lloyd's algorithm (this also seems to be the version presented in the question). It assigns points to clusters using the Euclidean distance (kind of per definition). This distance measure cannot be simply replaced by another.

See for example the `compute_centroids()` function. Here new centroids are calculated using the mean values of the cluster points (thus *k-means*). By doing so it is implicitely assumed that this new centroid is a better representative of the cluster then the previous one as it minimises the overall distance between the points of the cluster to the centroid. But this needn't be the case if the distance function is changed.
There are other variations using for example the median which could be combined with the Manhattan distance.

See this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric) for a far more detailed discussion.

---

*Quick addition to the algorithm to print out the cluster assignment distribution during each iteration*

```py
# imports ...

np.set_printoptions(precision=1)

# ... 

def k_means_algorithm(X, k, random_init, max_iters = 1000, return_obj=False):
    # ...
    while not np.array_equal(centroids,new_centroids) and counter < max_iters:
        # ...
        hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(cluster_assignments.flatten(), bins=k)
        hist = 100 * hist / hist.sum()
        print(hist)  # percentage of values assigned to each cluster
    return centroids, cluster_assignments

# ...
```

Caution: this only gives a rough impression how values are assigned to clusters and might level out for the full scale data set. Still, it works nicely for the sample data provided with the question.

- While the distribution more or less steadily converges to the final solution in case `cur_dist = np.linalg.norm(X[:, i] - centroids[:, j])` is used,
- it 'jumps' around for `cur_dist = wasserstein_distance(X[:, i], centroids[:, j])` for said reason that the centroids do not represent the centers of the clusters for the EMD.

Comment: But the thing is that I've read papers that have implemented k-means using the EMD. Are they are using other assignment metrics?

Comment: Difficult to say, without knowing the papers :) My guess would be, that these papers did not only change the distance measure in the standard k-means algorithm. But for example also the way the centroids are calculated. Him gives a nice example in the comments to the question, why using the arithmetic mean (as done in the question) will not minimise the EMD (i.e. the centroids will not be optimal representatives of the clusters). Another aspect that can make a difference on how the algorithm behaves are the characteristics of the data set.

Comment: These posts make it seem like it's possible: https://github.com/SaladRaider/pkmeans, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/using-k-means-with-other-metrics

Comment: Additionally, my colleague implemented it and it works, but its very slow because it's not vectorized.

Comment: Sure, you *can* use the EMD and it will give some result. But as also pointed out in the answers to the post you linked, it is not guaranteed that the algorithm converges to the optimal solution. Have you tried to make the behaviour of the algorithm transparent in your specific case? E.g. by printing the `cluster_assignments` in each iteration or (to get a quick first overview) by just printing how many elements are assigned to each cluster (I added this version to my answer).